# Strange '&' symbol on running Maven command via VSCode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

So I just got a new job and I've been setting up my new laptop since Wednesday.

I've tried some demo Spring Boot project (generate from Spring Initializr)

However when I try to clean/compile (Maven) it has strange "&" symbol and this is what's on the terminal

C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\TestProject\demo>& "c:\Users\xxxx\Documents\TestProject\demo\mvnw.cmd" clean -f "c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\TestProject\demo\pom.xml" 
**& was unexpected at this time**

Note that this happens when I use Maven command via VSCode only (both by clicking on Maven pane on Explorer tab, and using command palette.) Executing Maven command on terminals works fine.

Anyway to fix this? I'd be appreciated a lot because VSCode is my main editor/IDE.

Thanks!

Edit : It does work with PowerShell, but still doesn't work on Git Bash and Command Prompt. Maybe because I installed Windows Terminal and WSL2?

Comment: When you execute Maven commands in the terminal, are you using PowerShell or Windows Command Prompt? Is this the same terminal as opens within VSCode?

The `&` symbol in PowerShell is the [Call Operator] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-) which runs a command, script, or script block.

Comment: @WillWalsh The default terminal in VSCode is Command Prompt and I've tried changed it into the other two, doesn't work, still has the '&' symbol. However it only happens when I "click" or run command via VSCode palette. 

It works fine if I open a terminal 'inside' VSCode and type in the command (i.e. mvn clean compile) by myself but it doesn't work (has the '&" symbol) if I use the palette, or right-click on the Maven pane.

Comment: *****PS. Forgot to mention that I have three terminals, Command Prompt, PowerShell and Git Bash. Mainly I use Command Prompt and Git Bash

Comment: So I try again and it does work on PowerShell, maybe I have to use it instead of others. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure - good luck on your coding journey! :)